# Bounds on Christoffel symbols

Tags: smooth-manifolds, curvature

Let $\Omega$ be an open connected subdomain of a Riemannian manifold $M$ with boundary such that $\Omega$ is $\epsilon$ close to the boundary of $M$. Moreover, $\partial\Omega$ has two boundary components $\partial M\cup C$, where C is diffeomorph to $\partial M$.  I am wondering if we can get a uniform bound on Christoffel symbols of $\Omega$ in terms of Ricci (or sectional) curvature of the domain and the means curvatures of its boundaries.

Comment: The Christoffel symbol  is  not  a tensor. You need to explain what you mean by *bound* in this case since the sectional curvatures are coordinate independent, while the Christoffel symbols depend on coordinates.

Comment: Not likely. The Ricci curvature is intrinsic while the Christoffel symbols are highly coordinate dependent.

Comment: As the others say, you have to say more precisely what you mean by a uniform bound on Christoffel symbols. I believe that some kind of uniform bound can be obtained using harmonic coordinates. However, note that the bound has to depend on $\epsilon$, too.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I agree that the bound will depend on $\epsilon$. Let me clarify my question: does there exist an orthonormal frame $\{e_i\}$ such  that the of $\omega_{i,j}^k$, where $\omega_{i,j}^k$ are the coefficients in $\nabla_{e_i}e_j=\omega_{i,j}^ke_k$, can be bounded in terms of intrinsic geometry of $\Omega$ and $\partial\Omega$  namely Ricci, mean curvature etc?

Comment: I doubt it suffices to use the mean curvature only. I believe you need the whole second fundamental form on the boundary.

Comment: Also, solving for an orthonormal frame can be a pain. One thing that might work is to solve for a harmonic diffeomorphism from $\partial M\times [0,\epsilon]$ with the product metric to a tubular neighborhood of $\partial M$ in $M$. You should then be able to get a bound on the Christoffel symbol of the metric on $M$ relative to the product metric.

Comment: @DeaneYang thank you for the comment. Is it clear that there exist a harmonic diffeomorphism from $\partial M\times[0,\epsilon]$ with the product metric to a tubular neighborhood of $\partial M$ in $M$?

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, yes.